# Unable to update multiple documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update all documents that match the following criteria.

For some reason, I'm getting an error in the console saying that alerts.save is not a function.

This is how I've been updating my records.

Is the issue that I'm trying to update more than one document?

```
router.route('/mark_as_read/:ownerId')
.put(function(req, res){

  var alerts = new Alerts();

  Alerts.find({owner_id: req.params.ownerId}, function(err, alerts){
    if(err)
        res.send(err);

    alerts.viewed = true;
    console.log('Alerts: ', alerts);

    alerts.save(function(err){
      if(err)
        res.send(err);
      res.json(alerts)
    });
  });
});
```

Here is an example of the data returned when I do a get:

```
  { _id: 59aed31e78fbbea611518ddf,
    message: 'Hammer Hammer at hammer@example.com',
    alert_type: 'Share',
    owner_id: '59a6e66d5ab67150837d96a8',
    __v: 0,
    viewed: false,
    date: 2017-09-05T16:38:54.437Z },
  { _id: 59aed6035fee3fa895045693,
    message: 'Paul Pataa at paul@example.com',
    alert_type: 'Share',
    owner_id: '59a6e66d5ab67150837d96a8',
    __v: 0,
    viewed: false,
    date: 2017-09-05T16:51:15.193Z },
  { _id: 59aedba6fec346aafae9121c,
    message: 'Marky Mark at marks@example.com',
    alert_type: 'Share',
    owner_id: '59a6e66d5ab67150837d96a8',
    __v: 0,
    viewed: false,
    date: 2017-09-05T17:15:18.876Z },
  { _id: 59aedc36fec346aafae91228,
    message: 'Lilly Lap at sammy@example.com',
    alert_type: 'Share',
    owner_id: '59a6e66d5ab67150837d96a8',
    __v: 0,
    viewed: false,
    date: 2017-09-05T17:17:42.951Z }
```

I tried iterating over the alerts array, but this dis not work for me:

```
router.route('/mark_as_read/:ownerId')
.put(function(req, res){

  var alerts = new Alerts();

  Alerts.find({owner_id: req.params.ownerId}, function(err, alerts){
    if(err)
        res.send(err);

    for(var i=0; i < alerts.length; i++){
      alerts.viewed = true;
      alerts[i].save(function(err){
        if(err)
          console.log('Error in updating an alert');

      })
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **find** method will return an array so **alerts.save()** won't work.

You would have to iterate over the array and call **save()** on each document in the array.

Alternatively, you could use **findOne** instead, which will return a single document.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Makes sense. I updated my example with a loop over the alerts array, but this didn't work. Anywhere I can see a clear example of handling this? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: On this line **alerts.viewed = true** you are trying to reference a **viewed** property of the array itself. You might experience issues with doing it this way as the **save** calls will be async but the for loop will be sync. Therefore, i'd recommend using **findOne** or **findById** as you are only matching a single document anyway.

Comment: I'm actually trying to update all documents that have the same owner_id. So  using findOne or findById won't work in my case. There must be a simple way to update multiple documents. I found how to do it in mongo using the .update method, but that doesn't work in my express app. Have you ever searched through a collections and change a single field in each document returned? That's my challenge. Thanks again. I'm sure the answer is right in front of me. I'm just not getting it yet.  :-)

Comment: Give this a try using the **multi** option: **Alerts.update({owner_id: req.params.ownerId}, {viewed: true},  {multi: true}, function(err, numAffected) {...});** So the signature is: **Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback);**

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I actually found that in the docs and it worked. Appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it working.